# Calling method without class instantiating it

Tags: php

So I'm wanting to ditch some methods in some code and would like to not use the class instantiating and use the methods directly - How would I be able to convert `if (!Request::has_get('run')) {` into just calling the has_get function?

**run.php**

```php
if (!Request::has_get('run')) {
    echo 'Hello! This is Semirs Page';
}
```

**The method**:

```php
public static function has_get($key = '', $value = '')
    {
        return self::has_value($_GET, $key, $value);
    }
```

**My attempt which is incorrect**:

```
if (!isset($_GET(has_get['run'])) {
    echo 'Hello! This is Semirs Page';
}
```

Comment: Such call Request::has_get does not need class instantiating. It is static function

Comment: But it's looking for a Request class and then looking for the has_get method -> If I have the has_get method in the same .php file and I ditch the class file, how can I call it there?

Comment: `isset($_GET['run'])`

Comment: Not clear what's the purpose of this?

Comment: Need to strip some methods from a class and would like to avoid using the class::method call.

Comment: @splash58, that doesn't pickup my has_get method tho, does it?

Comment: You can't call a method with `has_get()` syntax. It's either `class::method()` or `$object->method()`.

Comment: `function has_get($a) { return Request::has_get($a); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ditch the class, just turn all the static functions into ordinary top-level functions, and remove `self::` when calling other methods in the class. So it becomes

```
function has_get($key = '', $value = '')
    return has_value($_GET, $key, $value);
}

function has_value($array, $key, $value) {
    return isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] === $value;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of wanting to remove the `Request` class.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the class completely, just make them all ordinary functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the same `.php` file you want to use the function, just declare it:

```
function has_get($key = '', $value = '')
{
    return has_value($_GET, $key, $value);
}
```

I'm not sure what you `Request::has_value()` function looks like, but you would need to declare that as well.